# How to convert a pandas dataframe to a geopandas dataframe?

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have a `DataFrame` called `NB` (New Buildings), which I am trying to convert to `GeoPandas` using the following process:

1. The column `Coordinates` is converted to a shapely object:

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   import geopandas
   from shapely.geometry import Point

   NB["Coordinates"] = NB["Coordinates"].apply(Point)
   ```
2. The `DataFrame NB` is converted to a `GeoPandas`, and I am assigning the column `Coordinates` to be the geometry:

   ```
   geo_df_NB = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(NB, geometry='Coordinates')
   ```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent 
call last)
<ipython-input-438-3adb06cd76f3> in <module>
----> 1 geo_df_NB = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(NB, geometry='Coordinates')

AttributeError: module 'geopandas' has no attribute 'GeoDataFrame'
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you have to other module called geopandas?

Comment: That is weird. Please can you show your import statements ... have you imported geopandas?

Comment: Please, show complete error traceback.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have edited my question and added all the modules that  I am using. I also added the complete error traceback.

Comment: It looks like you are working in a notebook, so you might have accidentally overwritten the `geopandas` variable. Can you try to restart the kernel and just run the code you have shown us. Or try to run `geopandas.__version__`

Comment: You just made my day. That worked. Thanks!